# Apple LED Cinema Display low resolution on Windows PC

Tags: windows, display, resolution, lcd, led

I have an old Apple Cinema Display 27" that has a mini-DisplayPort cable.
To use it with my laptop I've bought a USB-C to mini DisplayPort connector.
On linux I'm getting the full resolution (2560x1440). However on Windows the maximum resolution i can get is 1280x720.

On linux I use the following command at startup to set the resolution:

```
xrandr --newmode "2560x1440_47.00"  239.25  2560 2728 3000 3440  1440 1443 1448 1482 -hsync +vsync && xrandr --addmode DP-2 "2560x1440_47.00"
```

Is it possible to somehow export these settings to windows?

Comment: USB-C is often limited to two DisplayPort lanes. Combined with outdated DisplayPort versions, this is often not enough for high-resolution displays. If you use an adapter with four lanes, you will not have this problem.

Comment: Thanks. It now works but I can’t raise the refresh rate above 47.

Comment: Yes, that’s because you’re scratching the limits of two DP HBR lanes here (101% actually). I’m aware of one adapter that allows 4 lanes, from StarTech. Check the [press release here](https://www.startech.com/en-us/pr/usb-c-dual-monitor-multiport-adapters-with-display), it links to the products.

Comment: Thanks. They have full-sized displayport not Mini DisplayPort if I’m not mistaken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so this was easy using an app called [CRU](https://www.monitortests.com/forum/Thread-Custom-Resolution-Utility-CRU)

Here are the settings I used in case someone has the same problem:

[image]
[image]